# How to control variable width of line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, calligraphy

I want to make specific part of a path wider. 
Width tool (cs5) gives me unwanted results on the rest of the path.
Brushes do not offer control for bulge positions on long swirly paths.
Even calligraphy brushes. (I do not want "ribbons").

How people digitally make SPECIFIC lines for calligraphic fonts and swooshes?
How to get from this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/calligraphuck/12846010874/

to this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/calligraphuck/7483957036/

?

Thank you.

(Fastest and easy way is to use predefined brushes, but I want full control)

Update - width tool is insufficient because I get this:
[image: paddle]
 Line got narrower left from the point I inserted to reset width of that part of the path. How can I make it stay 10 points?

Comment: I think you'll need to expand on why the Width Tool is insufficient. This is exactly what it was designed to do and what, in my experience, it excels at.

Comment: Original post updated with details.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you've posted there are only a couple options I can think of.

Use the **Width Tool** and *add more width markers* to control areas of the path you wish to control. The goal of the width tool is to create a *smooth* transition between varied widths. So, yes, a large increase on one side of a marker will result in some decrease on the other side of the marker. The tool is keeping the curve smooth. If you do not want smooth curves, you need to use more width markers to indicate the actual widths you want. Note you can double-click a width marker with the Width Tool to set a precise size to the marker.

Or...

**Expand your paths** to shapes and alter the shapes. This is how things were done prior to the Width Tool being introduced, and I'd hazard a guess how many calligraphers building fonts work. Most type characters are shapes, not paths. While it may seem more helpful to keep everything as a path, if you want to adjust things beyond the capabilities of a path, you simply need to expand the path to a shape. If exact precision is needed, few "path altering" tools will provide that whereas it can easily be done with shapes.

--

Brushes may work, but will offer the least amount of control over appearance and from reading your question, that clearly won't be sufficient for you.

Comment: Crucial part in the question was - is it possible to set "other part" of the altered path to stay unaltered. Now I see that I am not missing anything in settings.

Comment: err... add a width marker to it. Set that marker to 10pts.